# send request to access of seller API of flipkart/amazon seller API CAKEPHP

Tags: php, curl

```
$url  = "https://api.flipkart.net/oauth-service/oauth/token\?grant_type\=client_credentials\&scope=Seller_Api";

$curl = curl_init(); 
$headers = array(
            'appid:130783468867102b10c21ab54ba3a7562a68038',
            'app-secret:2a27d5f4796a69f27233752fed1380ae91f'
            );

$json_data = json_encode($headers);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);                                                                   
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type:application/octet-stream',
    'Content-Length:'.strlen($json_data),
     ''
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
      $ee       = curl_getinfo($curl);
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($ee);
    curl_close($curl);


    print_r($result);
```

?>
OUTPUT

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.4.4
Date: Mon, 23 Nov 2015 07:26:51 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the backslashes from the url. Which should look like below:

```
$url  = "https://api.flipkart.net/oauth-service/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=Seller_Api";
```